# Cannot order Firebase data in Unity. C#

Tags: c#, firebase, unity-game-engine, firebase-realtime-database

I have search across the internet for where I am going wrong and cannot for the life of me find out why this data is not returning ordered. Can someone point out where I am going wrong in this code.... It should just be a simple high score table but just returns in order as in the database.

```
public void getHighScores() {
        FirebaseDatabase.DefaultInstance.GetReference("Scores").OrderByChild("score").LimitToLast(10).ValueChanged += HandleValueChanged;
}

void HandleValueChanged(object sender, ValueChangedEventArgs args) {
    if (args.DatabaseError != null) {
        Debug.LogError("Error: " + args.DatabaseError.Message);
        return;
    }
    // Do something with the data in args.Snapshot
    var highscoreobject = args.Snapshot.Value as Dictionary<string, System.Object>;
    //Debug.Log(args.Snapshot.Child("score").Value);
    foreach (var item in highscoreobject)
    {
        string userScore = "";
        //Debug.Log(item.Key); // Kdq6...
        var values = item.Value as Dictionary<string, System.Object>;
        var list = item.ToList();
        list.Sort();
        foreach (var v in values)
        {
            //Debug.Log(v.Key + ":" + v.Value); // category:livingroom, code:126 ...
            userScore += v.Value;
        }
        highscoreText.text += userScore+" \n";
    }
}
```

[image]

Thanks

Comment: What If you try orderByValue() instead of OrderByChild()?

Comment: It just returns the same order. I can't specify any value to order by with OrderByValue as it takes no arguments. Any other suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Items in a dictionary are by definition unordered. That means that as soon as you call `args.Snapshot.Value as Dictionary<string, System.Object>` any information about the order of the child nodes of the snapshot is lost.

If you want to maintain order you should loop over the children of the snapshot, and only call `.Value` when the order is not important anymore (i.e. when you get to the properties). So something like this:

```
void HandleValueChanged(object sender, ValueChangedEventArgs args) {
    if (args.DatabaseError != null) {
        Debug.LogError("Error: " + args.DatabaseError.Message);
        return;
    }
    foreach (DataSnapshot childSnapshot in snapshot.Children)
    {
        Debug.log(childSnapshot.Key+": "+childSnapshot.Child("uid").Value+" "+childSnapshot.Child("score").Value
    }
}
```

Comment: Awesome thank you. I'll try this later and see how I go. Is there a better way to output arrays in Unity instead of Debug.Log?

Comment: Hi @Frank, how can we find the rank of special user?